# Society6 embed image and link

Tags: php, jquery

I am looking to try and pull the images from my society6 shop into a PHP page. Currently I am using the following code which is provided by Society 6, which seems to only pull one image.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to pull all the images surrounded by a link with the Javascript or ideally with PHP so I can embed them

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
s6_user = "ThriftandThistle";
s6_format = "300x250";
//--></script>
<script type="text/>
```

http://society6.com/js/show_banner.js